# Pricing Calculation for Azure File Service

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am having a query related to pricing for Azure File Service that how pricing happens like as per usage of GB data of file or will it be based on available size for file share like 5TB per share.

I am referring this link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/ but this is not giving me the exact pricing.

My Scenario is like let’s say:-
1)   for two months I would require 4GB file data on File Share and then for another 4 month I would require 5GB of file data so how the costing will happen?
2)  Would I require two VMs for this to maintain the availability and how the costing will happen for two VMs usage?

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The price is per GB *used*.

Regarding your questions:

1. The share has a maximum if 5TB size, but you are only billed for what you actually use, not the maximum size. In your example, you will be billed for 4GB for the first 2 months, and 5GB for the next 4.
2. You do not require any VMs to maintain availability of the shares themselves - Azure Storage offers SLA on the share uptime. Of course, if you have an app that is running in a VM, and you need uptime guaranteed for the app, you have to look at how many VMs you need, but that is one level above storage - and those needs are not based on storage uptime considerations.